# Как запретить программе доступ к сайту?

Tags: windows, firewall, доступ

Есть программа, которая при запуске пытается получить доступ к сайту (например, ya.ru).

Как запретить ей доступ только по этому адресу, но оставить возможность подключения к другим? Причём все остальные программы должны иметь возможность подключиться к заблокированному сайту.  Если можно настроить через брандмауэр Windows, напишите пожалуйста, как.

Answer (score 1):

В С:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts добавь строку

```
 127.0.0.1 ya.ru
```

**UPD**. Не увидел за остальных. Если остальным программам -- то в некоторых антивирусах можно запретить доступ определенным программам на определенные сайты NOD SS так точно. А брандмауэр -- Пуск\администрирование\брандмауэр Windows в режиме повышенной безопасности, слева выбираете Правила для исходящего подключения, справа выбираете пункт Создать правило, дальше интуитивно понятно будет)

Answer (score 0):

[Outpost Firewall free](http://free.agnitum.com/)

Comment: Разве оутпост умеет для приложение доступ по URL блокировать?Не по IP адресу/сети.